Oracle APEX Popup LOV on IG
I'm working with Oracle APEX 23.2.3 (Latest Version) and I have an issue.
With a Multi Column Popup LOV on an Interactive Grid, I'm trying to set values for 2 columns. The Task ID column, which is the one that has the Popup LOV itself, and the Project ID column. I do this with Additional Output option.

This is the SQL Query for the IG.

As you can see, when the Popup LOV column is a NULL column, it works perfectly fine.

But when the Popup LOV column is a DB column, the situation is different.
First situation: if the row doesn't have a task, it works perfectly fine too.


Second situation: if the row does have a task, it throws an error, although it still works fine and sets both column values.


If I remove the PROJECTE_ID from Items to Submit to the Popup LOV, then the error is not thrown anymore and everything works fine.
I've tried many combinations until I found out where the problem was coming from, but I can't find a way to solve this.
Thanks in advance!
Cheers.

I understand that you have found out, that you shouldn't submit to an item that isn't defined on the page or at global scope. What is the issue that remains after you have removed "PROJECTE_ID" from "Items to Submit"?

@Markus If I remove "PROJECTE_ID" from "Items to Submit" it works well, but I need to be able to submit an item.

What happens if you create a page item "PROJECTE_ID" on that page?
